# Forming matrix from 2 vectors in Numpy, with repetition of 1 vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Using numpy arrays I want to create such a matrix most economically:
given

```
from numpy import array
a = array(a1,a2,a3,...,an)
b = array(b1,...,bm)
```

shall be processed to matrix M:

```
M = array([[a1,a2,b1,...,an],
           ...           ...,
           [a1,a2,bm,...,an]]
```

I am aware of numpy array's broadcasting methods but couldn't figure out a good way. 
Any help would be much appreciated,

cheers, 
Rob

Comment: So one element of `b` is inserted as the third element of every duplicate of `a` in the matrix?

Comment: yes, so if a=(1,2,3) and b=(4,5), let's say I want b in the 3rd column, my M = [[1,2,4,3],[1,2,5,3]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.resize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html) on `a` first and then add `b`'s items at the required indices using [`numpy.insert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) on the re-sized array:

```
In [101]: a = np.arange(1, 4)

In [102]: b = np.arange(4, 6)                                           

In [103]: np.insert(np.resize(a, (b.shape[0], a.shape[0])), 2, b, axis=1)                                                                       
Out[103]: 
array([[1, 2, 4, 3],                                                    
       [1, 2, 5, 3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `numpy.tile` and `numpy.hstack` functions.

```
M = numpy.repeat(numpy.hstack(a, b), (N,1))
```

I'm not sure I understand your target matrix, though.